# Remove Hardcoded Folder Path in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

In my project I am referring to a folder:

```
string path=Path.Combine(@"E:\Per\kamlendra.sharma\Windows\main\software\my.software\my.software.Server\Resources", string.Format("LocalizationDictionary.{0}.xaml", SelectedNewLanguage.culture));
```

But I don't want to hard code this address:

`@"E:\Per\kamlendra.sharma\Windows\main\software\my.software\my.software.Server\Resources"`

Can anyone please suggest a better approach?

Comment: Do you want to get application path alike IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)?

Comment: What do you want to use the resulting path for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store application data in [app.config](http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=howtos&id=20)

Answer (score 1):

The UNC path of the currently executing assembly can be obtained.  You can then use this as the basis to access the specific subfolder - this is assuming the folder you are looking for is the a subfolder of where the assembly is located...

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location //This actually returns the assembly file name, so you would need to use FileInfo to get the folder location.
```

A better approach is probably System.Appdomain, which gives you access to the location of the actuall WPF application rather than the assembly.

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to configure and use application data files.

- [WPF Application Resource, Content, and Data Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx)